# Solving $\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{e^x-e^{-2x}+2}$ with substitution

Tags: integration

$$\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{e^x-e^{-2x}+2}$$

I've tried solve this with substitution, first with $ u = e^x$ witch gives me $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{u\left(1 - \frac{1}{e^2}\right)+2} du$ and second with $ u = e^x-e^{-2x}$ witch gives me $\int_0^1\frac{u}{u - \frac{u}{e^2}+2-\frac{2}{e^2}}du$. None of these seems any good to continue with.

== Edit ==
Forget a +2 term in the first statement  (that's why the substitutions seemed wrong (or at least a part of why))

Comment: the first substitution feels correct. You have to use $u=e^x$. however your result is wrong. if you can write your steps, we can tell you where your mistake is. (take into account that you have to change the edges as well)

Comment: I noticed that substituting $u=e^{-x}$ gives a slightly simpler integral, $\int \frac{du}{u^3 - 1}$. Then it's just partial fractions.

Comment: @DepeHb Partial fractions are not useful, as explained on the page.

Comment: Which page? I don't understand.

Answer (score 2):

*The OP now modified the question to take into account the remark made at the end of this answer. I leave this answer as it is.*

The substitution $u=\mathrm e^x$ yields $\mathrm dx=\frac1u\mathrm du$ and $\mathrm e^{-2x}=\frac1{u^2}$ hence the integral to be computed is
$$
\int_1^\mathrm e\frac{\mathrm du}{u\cdot(u-\frac1{u^2})}=\int_1^\mathrm e\frac{u\cdot\mathrm du}{u^3-1},
$$
not what you wrote. Can you continue?

By the way, the integral diverges, that is,
$$
\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm e^x-\mathrm e^{-2x}}=+\infty.
$$

Comment: why is $dx = 1/udu$?

Comment: It is not, please read.

Comment: Yes the integral diverges!+1

Comment: The OP previously asked why $dx=1/u$, hence my comment. Now their question is why $dx=1/udu$. Probably this means $dx=du/u$, which is explained by the change of variable $u=\mathrm e^x$, $x=\log u$.

Comment: OP: Did you downvote this, by any chance?

Comment: OP: Did you undownvote this, by any chance?

Comment: @Did I downvoted it for an error that's now been corrected. So, -1$\Rightarrow$+1 ;)

Comment: @DavidH Silently? Nice. On an answer to a question you are answering yourself? Doubly nice.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$\frac{1}{e^x-e^{-2x}+2}=\frac{e^{2x}}{e^{3x}-1+2e^{2x}}$$

Substituting $u=e^x$, we have $du=e^xdx$ and

$$\int_0^1\frac{1}{e^x-e^{-2x}+2}dx=\int_0^1\frac{e^{x}}{e^{3x}+2e^{2x}-1}e^{x}dx\\
=\int_{1}^{e}\frac{u}{u^3+2u^2-1}du.$$