# Evaluate $\int_{1}^{e}\frac{u}{u^3+2u^2-1}du.$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I'm trying to solve

$$\int_{1}^{e}\frac{u}{u^3+2u^2-1}du.$$

My first approach was to factorise and then do a partial integration. However the factorisation $(u+1)\left(u+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2} \right)\left(u+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2} \right)$ leads me to heavy calculations. How would you proceed to solve this?

This is a continued calculation of [Solving $\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{e^x-e^{-2x}+2}$ with substitution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/778322/solving-int-01-fracdxex-e-2x2-with-substitution)

Comment: Partial fractions is the right track. Unfortunately, sometimes is quite tedious. You are in the right track !!!.

Answer (score 2):

As $$u^3+2u^2-1=(u+1)(u^2+u-1)$$

Write,
$$\frac u{u^3+2u^2-1}=\frac A{u+1}+B\frac{\dfrac{d(u^2+u-1)}{du}}{u^2+u-1}+\frac C{u^2+u-1}$$

$$u=A(u^2+u-1)+(2Bu+B)(u+1)+C(u+1)$$

Set $\displaystyle u+1=0$ to find $A$

Now comparing the coefficients of $u^2$, $0=A+2B\iff B=?$

Again comparing the constants $0=-A+B+C\implies C=?$

Observe that the second integral $\displaystyle\int B\frac{\dfrac{d(u^2+u-1)}{du}}{u^2+u-1}du=B\int\frac{d(u^2+u-1)}{u^2+u-1}=?$

For the third,  $\displaystyle\int\frac C{u^2+u-1}=4C\int\frac{du}{(2u+1)^2-(\sqrt5)^2}$

use $\#1$ of  [this](http://www.sosmath.com/tables/integral/integ9/integ9.html)

Or set $\displaystyle 2u+1=\sqrt5\sec\theta$

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how that would help me. To me, that just looks more confusing.

Comment: @iveqy He's showing that you can split the fraction into ones that are easier to work with.

Comment: @oliveeuler yes I understand that. And that was my approach to, however I've learnt that you need to fully factorise before you can do that. He's using some clever trick involving the derivator of $u^2+u-1$ so avoid factorising. How does that work?

Comment: @labbhattacherjee Could you explain how you can do a partial integration without fully factorise the denominator?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Obserse that $u^3 + 2u^2 -1$ has $u+1$ as a factor.

Comment: I did, see the factorisation above. But how to proceed then?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$u^3+2u^2-1=(u+1)(u^2+u-1).$$  Completing the square $$ u^2+u-1= u^2+u\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{4}-1=(u+1/2)^2-5/4.$$

Now use partial fraction
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{(u+1)((u+1/2)^2-5/4)}=\frac{A}{u+1}+\frac{Bu+C}{( u+1/2)^2-5/4}
\end{align}
We find that $ A=-1, B=1, C=0$, so that 
\begin{align}
I&=\int { \frac{-1}{u+1} du}+\int{ \frac{u}{(u+1/2)^2-5/4}du}
\\
&=-\ln ( u+1 )+J
\end{align}
now to find $ J$, since $$denominator= \frac{5}{4}\left({  (\frac {2}{\sqrt 5}  (u+1/2))^2-1 }\right)$$ we assume $(\frac{2}{\sqrt5}(u+1/2))= w$ to get
\begin{align}
J=constant \int\frac{\sqrt5 w-1}{w^2-1}dw
\end{align}
Finally, setting $ w=\sec\theta $ and proceed $\cdots $

Comment: I don't understand the middle expression of your second equation...

Comment: You can proceed now